# C# Algorithm for converting Visual LTR to Logic RTL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam working on a project in Unity3d, using C# scripting, with strings that are written in Hebrew and English.
The problem with Unity3d is that RTL languages (like Hebrew) are not supported when writing UI texts.

The problem looks like this:
original text:
מערכת העטלף הינה מערכת, אשר מתבססת על טכנולוגית ה- GPR 
(Ground Penetrating Radar) - ראדאר חודר קרקע.

in unity:
GPR -ה תיגולונכט לע תססבתמ רשא ,תכרעמ הניה ףלטעה תכרעמ
.עקרק רדוח ראדאר - (Ground Penetrating Radar)

Iam trying to hack the order that the text is printed to the text boxes for a month now and I cant get it just right.
I made up the following function:

```
    public string CorrectText (string text)
{
    string result = "";
    string temp = "";
    string charListString = "";
    List<Char> charList = new List<char> ();
    char[] charArray = text.ToCharArray ();

    Array.Reverse (charArray);

    //go through each char in charArray
    for (int x = 0; x <= charArray.Length -1; x++) {
        //if the current char we're examing isn't a Space char -
        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace (charArray [x])) {
            //add it to charList
            charList.Add (charArray [x]);
        } else { //if the current char we're examing is a Space char -
            charListString = new string (charList.ToArray ());

            //if charListString doesn't contains English or Numeric chars -
            if (!Regex.IsMatch (charListString, "^[0-9a-zA-Z.,()-]*$")) {
                //go through each char in charList 
                for (int y = 0; y <= charList.Count - 1; y++) {
                    //add the current char to temp as is (not flipped)
                    temp += charList [y];
                }

                //add temp to result
                if (x < charArray.Length - 1)
                    result += temp + " ";
                if (x == charArray.Length - 1)
                    result += temp;

                //clear charList and temp
                charList.Clear ();
                temp = "";
            } else { //if temp contains English or Numeric chars -
                //go through each char in charList - This flipps the order of letters
                for (int y = charList.Count - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
                    //add the current char to temp
                    temp += charList [y];
                }

                //add temp to result
                if (x < charArray.Length - 1)
                    result += temp + " ";
                if (x == charArray.Length - 1)
                    result += temp;
                //clear charList and temp
                charList.Clear ();
                temp = "";
            }
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

this almost fixed the problem, but the text is written from bottom up for example:

input:
מערכת העטלף הינה מערכת, אשר מתבססת על טכנולוגית ה- GPR 
(Ground Penetrating Radar) - ראדאר חודר קרקע.

output:
(Ground Penetrating Radar) - ראדאר חודר קרקע.
מערכת העטלף הינה מערכת, אשר מתבססת על טכנולוגית ה- GPR

and sometimes the parenthesis are getting mixed up in the sentence, showing like this:
)Ground Penetrating( Radar - ראדאר חודר קרקע.

I've found a tool online that turns Visual Hebrew to Logic Hebrew, and when I copied the flipped text to unity it worked like magic!

But I cant find any useful information online on how to make my own script with C# that does the  same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome this... sort of:

1. Assign the string into the text element.
2. Force the canvas to update using `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases()`, or another means.
3. Get the cached text generator (NOT for layout) of the text component. It will lie to you if you didn't force an update or yielded and waited for the next frame; so don't skip step 2.
4. Use `getLines` of the cached text generator to get the information of the text wrapping; it holds the index where every line starts.
5. Take the maximum difference in the values of those and you have the likely amount of characters per row before it wraps.
6. Insert '\n' (new line) into the original string manually using the row length you found in the previous step **before** flipping the characters!
7. Do the reversal process on the wrapped string. If you do these things in a different order you will end up with the first line being the shortest, instead of the last. So wrap first, reverse second.
8. Set the string to the text component and it should work. Usually.

Comment: The line count doesn't always return the correct value, especially if you use a larger font (not size, the font itself) and I'm stomped by this.